# Как прочитать оглавление документа word на python?

Tags: python, ms-word, docx, doc

Мне нужно обработать массив документов doc и docx на Python, из которых нужно извлечь оглавления. С помощью каких инструментов можно прочитать оглавление, созданное специальным инструментом MS Word и оглавление созданное вручную в виде нумерованного списка или каким нибудь еще способом вручную(в массиве документов есть как оглавления созданные инструментом так и вручную).

Comment: pywin32, python-docx, xml.etree.ElementTree выбирайте по душе.